# How does the rewrite annotation in ingress work in k8s?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I am having difficulty in understanding the rewrite annotation in k8s ingress. Can someone please help me in understanding it with an example.

For Eg:

```
annotations:
   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
```

I checked this [Link](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/) out but it's still not very clear how the slashes and arguments work out here.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58604021/expose-a-kubernetes-deployment-frontend-using-ingress-controller/58604282#58604282) stackoverflow post, this will be helpful for you.

In this post you can see that hostname/api points to backend service, and the rewrite actually makes the url to get converted from hostname/api to hostname.

Rewrite comes handy when frontend and backend services are to be mapped to one hostname only