# Kubernetes ingress domain redirect

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

i want to redirect domain in nginx ingress kubernete.

```
https://test.example.io/preview/qLxiVcDGxCaQ134650121853FTg4
```

if in url `preview` comes change domain redirect

```
https://test.app.example.io/preview/qLxiVcDGxCaQ134650121853FTg4
```

what i was trying

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: staging
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  name: staging-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: test.example.io
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: service-1
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /preview/*
        backend:
          url: 
          serviceName: service-2
          servicePort: 80
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - test.example.io
    secretName: staging
```

for simple nginx block is like

```
location ~ /preview
    {
      rewrite /preview https://test.app.example.com$uri permanent;
    }
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

My logic thinking, try it :

```
metadata:
      annotations:
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
         rewrite /preview https://test.app.example.com$uri permanent;

spec:
      rules:
      - host: test.example.io
        http:
          paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: service-1
              servicePort: 80
      - host: test.app.example.io
        http:
          paths:
          - path: /preview/*
            backend:
              serviceName: service-2
              servicePort: 80
```

Hope it works !

On code above: You should not access using: https://test.app.example.io/preview/ (It just be redirected link ) at all.

Comment: Thanks for writing answer i used `server-snippet` instead of `configuration-snippet` now it's working. Thanks once again.

Comment: How you Can manage public IP for sub domain ?

Comment: that annotations line is magic. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Used nginx ingress annotation

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      location ~ /preview {
         rewrite /preview https://test.app.example.com$uri permanent;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

I may be late for OP but I don't think the accepted solution completely answers the original question.

We can use NGINX's [conditional URL rewrites](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if) offered by the `ngx_http_rewrite_module` to detect if a host matches the initial domain before redirecting to the new host. Here, the condition is based on the host name : `$host` ([other vars are also available in NGINX](http://nginx.org/en/docs/varindex.html), for a more advanced configuration).

```yaml
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
  if ($host = "<OLD_HOSTNAME>") {
    rewrite /preview $scheme://<NEW_HOSTNAME>$uri permanent;
  }
```

Also, and I'm in accordance with OP's comment on that point, I would not recommend using [`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet`](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations.md#configuration-snippet) for such custom configuration, as this kind of snippet would add the custom configuration into the `location` block of each ingress rule.

Instead, if we still want to use annotation snippets, use a [`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet`](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations.md#server-snippet) to add a configuration that would apply to the whole NGINX instance. Also, it could lead to [unexpected results](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: staging
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  name: staging-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: test.example.io
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: service-1
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /preview/(.*)
        backend: 
          serviceName: service-2
          servicePort: 80
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - test.example.io
secretName: staging
```

---

You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58604021/expose-a-kubernetes-deployment-frontend-using-ingress-controller/58604282#58604282) too, representing synonymous kind of issue

Comment: i want to redirect from `test.example.com` to `test.app.example.com`

Comment: you can add different host entry for that

Comment: how to add new host entry mean ?

Comment: one host is test.example.com, other can be test.app.example.com, and you can map the backend services to them in the respect .yaml manifests

Comment: but if i will new host entry it will check path `preview ` for that host. if contain or not. while i want to check on domain `test.example.com` and redirect to `test.app.example.com`