# Nginx Ingres Redirect only on path to another server

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have setup nginx ingress like this on kubernetes

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: animefanz-ktor-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - mydomain.com
      secretName: my-tls
  rules:
    - host: mydomain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /myapp(/|$)(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: myservice
              servicePort: 8080
```

So everything working fine but i want to do one thing when ever https://mydomian.com/myapp/api/history called then i want to redirect it to https://mydomain2.com/myapp2/api/history along with get params that is.

So i want to just forward one api request to another server.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can configure it with nginx [server-snippet](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#server-snippet)/[configuration-snippet](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#configuration-snippet) annotation.

---

There is related [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58687909/kubernetes-ingress-domain-redirect) about that.

And examples provided by @Thanh Nguyen Van

```
metadata:
      annotations:
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
         rewrite /preview https://test.app.example.com$uri permanent;

spec:
      rules:
      - host: test.example.io
        http:
          paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: service-1
              servicePort: 80
      - host: test.app.example.io
        http:
          paths:
          - path: /preview/*
            backend:
              serviceName: service-2
              servicePort: 80
```

And @Harsh Manvar

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
          location ~ /preview {
             rewrite /preview https://test.app.example.com$uri permanent;
          }
  name: staging-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: test.example.io
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: service-1
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /preview/*
        backend:
          url: 
          serviceName: service-2
          servicePort: 80
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - test.example.io
    secretName: staging
```

---

Additionally there is related [github issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/605) about that.

Hope you find this useful.