# nginx ingress redirect base on hostname

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

We have an application running in kubernetes using nginx ingress.
Now we want to replace the domain name and we want the old domain to redirect to this new domain.
What I need to do the get it work?

I can simply add the new domain as an additional hostname in my ingress configuration, but the problem is that the application can only work with one hostname.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kubernetes ingress domain redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58687909/kubernetes-ingress-domain-redirect)

Comment: No, that will redirect all traffic to a different domain, not based on specific domain

Comment: Anything you have tried so far? Could you also share your current configs?

Comment: I can create a separate ingress just for the redirection. Just wonder if it can be done in the same ingress.

Comment: Could you share your configs with us?